# How to know which thread is running my method?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using loop to start multiple threads which will execute my method "ThreadFunc".
 I am giving each thread a name.

**In my method "ThreadFunc", how to know which thread (thread name) is running my method?**

**My Method:**

```
 static void ThreadFunc()
    {
        lock (oLock)
        { //some work
        }
```

**Loop Starting Threads:**

```
static Dictionary<string, Thread> ThreadsCollection = new Dictionary<string, Thread>(); 
foreach (string s in AllFiles)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadFunc));
            thread.Name = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("doc"));
            thread.Start();
            ThreadsCollection.Add(thread.Name, thread);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In my method "ThreadFunc", how to know which thread (thread name) is running my method?

Get at the current thread with [`Thread.CurrentThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentthread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and then just use the [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.name%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
string currentThreadName = Thread.CurrentThread.Name;
```

Comment: @ನಿಶಿತ್: Please don't add comments to unrelated answers. That's basically comment spam.

Comment: Yes, I understand and I deleted it.